# React-Router Link Button not with Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a very simple react app.

In the main `App.js` I have a `Router`with my routes.

In another separate component, `PostItem`, which lives in `MainComponent`, I have a `Link` button to another component, `JobPost`.

I keep getting:

`Cannot GET /job/7`

Does this set up work? Or do I need to have a `Router` element in my component with my `Link`?

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MainComponent from './index.js';
import JobPost from './components/JobPost.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";


const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" exact component={MainComponent} />
      <Route path="/job/:id" exact component={JobPost} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

PostItem.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function PostItem(props){
  return(
    <div className="post-item">
    <div className="job-details">
      <h2 className="job-title" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:  props.title  }} />
      <h3 className="job-location"> Test Company - <i>Test Location</i></h3>
      <div className="job-description">
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:  props.content  }} />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button className="view-btn">
      <Link to={ `/job/` + props.id } >
        View
      </Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

JobPost.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//make actual class and render again

export default class JobPost extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        id: this.props.match.params.id
      };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      //fetch id from component
      console.log(this.state.id);
    }

    render(){
      return(
      <div className="post-container">
      <div className="job-details">
        <h2 className="job-title" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:  props.title  }} />
        <h3 className="job-location"> Test Company - <i>Test Location</i></h3>
        <div className="job-description">
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:  props.content  }} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="apply-btn">Apply</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In the `PostItem.js` if you `console.log` props - does it have an id?

Comment: having the `Router` inside the component which uses `Link` won't be necessary. If you try to call `/job` path without the param, does it work? If you try to use `<Switch>` rather than `<BrowserRouter>` to nest the routes, does it work?

Comment: @SakoBu I get the `id` if I `console.log` in `PostItem`

Comment: @Van nope switching to `Switch` did not work, and navigating to `/job` also did not work

Comment: So I was able to get it to work when clicking my button, but strangely it doesn't work if I try to directly type in the URI? So sharing the link or even refreshing the page gets me `Cannot GET /job/5`